# Validating number of attachments with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I referred http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Dynamic-multiple-image-uploads-with-Ruby-on-Rails
to allow multiple images to be attached. It works great.

Now I need a way to validate the number of attachments being attached. For example, it would throw a flash notice when there are more than 3 photos being attached.

Thanks !

**EDIT**

Here's the params hash being passed :

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "issue"=>{"photos_attributes"=>{"1291720762205"=>{"data"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20101207-16532-1l7ni0g-0>}, "1291720780898"=>{"data"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20101207-16532-rextw-0>}}}
```

In the view, I've just referenced the helper. And the helper is exactly the same as its showed in the tutorial which I referred.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to params that are being posted in the controller and check out the number of files been posted . You can use a before_filter to inspect the number of files attached in the params .If you can show us the code snippet , then probably I would be able to help with more details :)

Comment: Thats a step forward ! Thanks! Which part of the code would you need? Would you also need the params hash that is being passed?

Comment: yes.. send me a gist to your view and the printout the params that are being passed to the controller